# Time complexity of the given code

Tags: c++, time-complexity

Can someone tell me complexity of the bellow code.

```
    std::cin>>n1;
    int ctr=0;
    for(int i=2;i<=n1;i++)
    {
      if(i>=n/2&&ctr==0)
      {
        cout << " You entered a prime no";
        break;
       }
    else if(n1%i==0)
      {
        ctr++;
        cout<<i<<" ";
        n1/=i;
      }
}
```

Can someone suggest how to calculate the complexity of such loops which involve multiple if-else conditions?

Comment: your loop is `O(infinity)`

Comment: Yes, the `for` loop is O(1). What would the multiple if-else conditions be doing?

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay What sort of blasphemy is this?

Comment: In case TemplateRex's comment didn't ring a bell - you've got division by zero.

Comment: And if you start i at 1, you'll never get to 2, and if you start at 2 you'll still have trouble if n starts out at 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner loop is `O(1)`. The complexity of the outer loop depends on what the code does with `n`, and you didn't show the code, so it could be anything.

As to a general guideline: asymptotic complexity is always with respect to a quantity. Usually, this is taken to be input size (whatever that means for the problem being solved) and denoted `n`. In your case, it could very well be the variable `n`, seeing as it's used for the loop stop condition.

Once you know the quantity (the `n`) with respect to  which you want complexity, it's simple. Operations which don't depend on `n` are `O(1)`. Operations which do `O(f)` amount of work for each value of `n` are `O(n * f)`, where `f` can indeed be a function of `n`. It gets more tricky with recursion, but this is the basic overview.

Comment: Talking about the inner loop - If it wasn't i<=9 rather i <= n, a variable, it would be O(n) right?

Comment: @Bloodcount Yes (at least in the case the body doesn't modify `n`). In the OP's updated case, I'd have to think whether the division is enough to reduce it to `O(log(n))`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int n;
std::cin >> n;

// O(oo) e.g. O(infinite)
while( n > 0 ) {
    // for loop is O(1)
    for(int i = 1 ; i <= 9 ; i++) {
       if( n % i == 0) {
           //piece of code involving O(1)complexity.
       }
    }
    // this makes the while loop O(1)
    if ( n == 10000000000000 ) {
        break;
    }
}
```

this algorithm is O(1)

Comment: So you can divide by zero?

Comment: excuse me? what you mean? i dont think i can divide by zero.. ;)

Comment: Lol, n % i when i = 0 is dividing by 0.

Comment: @JohnOdom and also `n/=i;`

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay I know, but that one seems more obvious than the modulus operator.

Answer (score 0):

The Complexity of a for loop is `O(n)` where n is the number of iterations...

Here `n=9` , but it is wrong to take as conclusion that for loop in general is stable (`O(1)`) and not relevant to the number of iterations